# maintain values in view model between screen navigations

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a view model whose value is updated by Screen1 but I want Screen 2 to get those values:

```
@HiltViewModel
class VM @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {

var appState :Boolean by mutableStateOf(false)
}

@Destination
@Composable
fun ScreenOne(nav: DestinationsNavigator, vm: VM = hiltViewModel()){
   //update the vm here.
   vm.appState.value = true;
   nav.navigate(ScreenTwoDestination());
}

@Destination
@Composable
fun ScreenTwo(vm: VM = hiltViewModel()){
    Log.i(vm.appState); // this never changes and is also false even though the vm was correctly updated before the navigation happened.
}
```

How can ScreenTwo have the modified data of the view model?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that a new instance of the ViewModel can't access a previous ViewModel's state.  You have to pass the ViewModel variable rather than creating a new one.

I don't usually recommend doing this across `Navigation`, but you need to pass your `vm` value from `ScreenOne` as an argument to the receiving `@Composable`, `ScreenTwo`.  You'll also need to update your `Navigation` code so it can accept the incoming argument and pass it to `ScreenTwo`.

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class VM @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {

var appState :Boolean by mutableStateOf(false)
}

@Destination
@Composable
fun ScreenOne(nav: DestinationsNavigator, vm: VM = hiltViewModel()){
   vm.appState.value = true;
   // notice how I added the "vm" variable as an argument
   // This allows us to pass the existing instance of the ViewModel
   nav.navigate(ScreenTwoDestination(vm));
}

@Destination
@Composable
fun ScreenTwo(vm: VM = hiltViewModel()){
    Log.i(vm.appState);
```

On the other hand, you could also just hoist the `ViewModel` out of the `@Composables` all together:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class VM @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {

var appState :Boolean by mutableStateOf(false)
}
val vm = hiltViewModel()

@Destination
@Composable
fun ScreenOne(nav: DestinationsNavigator){
   vm.appState.value = true;
   nav.navigate(ScreenTwoDestination());
}

@Destination
@Composable
fun ScreenTwo(){
    Log.i(vm.appState);
```

For the record, both of these are not ideal options.  Best option is to handle the data elsewhere and to have two separate ViewModels that can access it.